# ag-grid react table not displaying?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

New to react and ag-grid.  I'm trying to implement a trivial example of ag-grid in my react project.  When I run the project, the grid doesn't display.  No console warnings, just the grid doesn't display.

```
import React from 'react';
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import '../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-material.css';

var headers =  [{headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 150, filter: 'text'},
                {headerName: 'Last', field: 'last', width: 150, filter: 'text'}]

var data = [{name: 'bob', last:'dude'},
            {name: 'will', last:'willdude'}]


export default class Accounts extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showGrid: true,
        columnDefs: headers,
        rowData: data,
    };
  }
  onGridReady(params) {
      this.api = params.api;
      this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  render() {
    var gridTemplate;
    gridTemplate = (
        <div  className="ag-material">
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
                showGrid={this.state.showGrid}
            />
        </div>
    );
    return (
      <div style={{width: '800px'}}>
        <p>I see this</p>
        {gridTemplate}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: This is what I see when I run this]

Comment: Having the same problem. Got answer?

Answer (score 10):

Okay got it, we need height on the parent div.

e.g.

```
    <div  className="ag-material" style={{height: '500px'}}>
        <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
            showGrid={this.state.showGrid}
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow. Wasted 30 mins looking for this.

Comment: You have saved me from endless frustration

Comment: but using a percent value for height collapses the table back down to a line again.

Answer (score 2):

its always better to give height and width otherwise ag-grid table will render by adjusting it to fit min content.

```
<div className="ag-material" style={{height: 500, width: 500}}>
        <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
            showGrid={this.state.showGrid}
        />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue when the grid was not rendering. Adding the grid styles fixed the problem for me.

```js
import '../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
```

```js
import '../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-material.css';
```