# AG Grid Dynamic Grid Size

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to make the AG Grid fit the size of the screen dynamically e.g. laptop screen, additional monitor which is bigger. So the size of the grid needs to be dynamic There shouldn't be any white space below the grid. I have a header and footer and the grid needs to fit between these. There should be not overlay. Any idea on how to do this?

The code below works fine with a smaller screen but when the screen is bigger there is white space. Then if I change the height percentage, the grid overlays the footer on the smaller screen not the larger screen.

```
.grid {
  @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
    height: 86%;
  }
  @media (min-width: 2001px) and (max-width: 6000px) {
    height: 92%; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835566/ag-grid-react-table-not-displaying/40966032#40966032) is similar although not *exactly* what you're trying.

My team is trying to do something similar with dynamic table sizes and we have been forced to "eyeball it" and set a defined height.

Would love if someone else could answer this more fully as we could leverage the dynamic table as well.